# leafletjs - move popup to a side panel

Tags: leaflet, popup

I've been playing around with popups, in conjunction with a geojson wrapped inside JavaScript and have mastered what I need to do on the bindpopup front. Now I'd like to effectively unbind the popup from its marker and get the popup to appear either in a side panel or below the map in its own div.

This is the code for my current popup and I'm guessing that I need to change my code around the area of layer.bindPopup(popupContent) and reference it to its own div?

```js
<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.4946, -0.7235], 11)
    var basemap =
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'OSM data',
    }).addTo(map);

    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        var popupContent = "<b>" + feature.properties.ward_names +
                " </b><br>Population 2011 = <b>" + feature.properties.census_11 + 
                " </b><br>Population 2001 = <b>"+ feature.properties.census_01 +
                " </b><br>You can find out more about population data on the <a href='http://www.somewhere.com' target='_blank'>somewhere.com</a> website ";

        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {

            popupContent += feature.properties;
        }

        layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    }
    
    L.geoJson([wardData], {
        style:  function (feature) {
            return { weight: 1.5, color: "#000000", opacity: 1, fillOpacity: 0 };
            return feature.properties;
        },
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
    }).addTo(map);
</script>
```

However I'm not really sure how to do this and need some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer shared under another question, https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/144501/44746

> If you're looking for populating another element entirely that you've
> defined outside of the map, then you actually don't need even the
> whole info control. You can just as easily do what you need in the
> onEachFeature >> layer.on >> click part too.

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        click: function populate() {
            document.getElementById('externaldiv').innerHTML = "BLAH BLAH BLAH " + feature.properties.name + "<br>" + feature.properties.description;
        }
    }); }
```

> In your html body, you just have to make sure your `<div id="externaldiv">` or whatever is placed where you want it.
>
> This demo populates an external  when the user clicks on a map
> feature : <strike>http://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-geojson-list/</strike>     (Edit: link reported broken as of dec 2022)

Comment: Your link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

The L.Control class is the appropriate tool for what you want to do.

I suggest you follow this [tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html), it will give you a quick understanding of what you can do with it.

Comment: Cheers for the pointer. So, I've taken the tutorial sample and put into into my html and using firebug to inspect the code, I can see the element (if that's the right term) of the l.control called 'this._div' through css puts it on the top-right of the map. I removed the css in the tutorial but the text set in the 'this._div.innerHTML' still remains on the left of the map. I tried changing the div tag from 'info' to 'info2' and referenced my side panel div to 'info2' but text is still off to the top-right.

Comment: try a float: left; somewhere

Comment: I still can't work this one out, I simply dont understand how to override the class and/or function putting the content of the popup in the top right-hand corner of the map.  I did some more fishing around on the net and came acorss this example (http://chris-osm.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/leaflet.html) that uses a getElementbyID call but again I can't seem to work out exactly how its working.

Comment: Don't override the function, change the css.